# chrome.action.setBadgeText: Tab specific to Global

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

`chrome.action.setBadgeText()` without tabId sets "global" badge text.
`chrome.action.setBadgeText()` with tabId sets "tab specific" badge text.
But I can't change tab specific badge text with global method.

```
chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: "tab specific", tabId: 'current tab id' });
chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: "global" }); // This won't show on this tab because I used tab specific method once.
chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: "change", tabId: 'current tab id' }); // Instead, this will work, but I can't use like this for my project.
```

Is there a way to stop the tab specific mode and change it back to global mode?

Comment: No, https://crbug.com/1353513.